# algorithm2e - Different ending words for switch and case blocks

Tags: algorithm2e

In the following MWE, I would like the end of `switch` to be different from the ends of `case` and  `other`. Is it possible ?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \Begin{
        \Switch{X}{
            \Case{1}{
                \While{Continue}{Action}
            }
            \Other{Other}
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

It appears to be easier to change it for Case than Otherwise, but this seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[longend]{algorithm2e}
\makeatletter

\SetKwFor{Case}{case}{}{end case}%

\renewcommand\algocf@Other[1]{%
\KwSty {otherwise}\algocf@block {#1}{\@algocf@endoption {end other}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \Begin{
        \Switch{X}{
            \Case{1}{
                \While{Continue}{Action}
            }
            \Other{Other}
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```